# How to show information in a table depending of the attribute value (XML-XSLT)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I want to show the table with the values of the selected month in the dropdownlist, first i have the table hidden, with a function in javascript I show the table, now I don´t know how to show just the information relative to this month.
could be with an if sentence in the xsl code? Thnks.

books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tabla.xsl"?>
<TotalBooks>
    <books month= "January">
       <book>
         <isbn> 1 </isbn>
         <tittle>The tittle</tittleo>
         <author>Me</author>
       </book>
       <book>
         <isbn> 2 </isbn>
         <tittle>The tittle two</tittleo>
         <author>Me</author>
       </book>
    </books>
</TotalBooks>
```

books.xsl

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function TryOption() 
      { 
         tabla.style.visibility="visible";          
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My books</h1>
    <div>
      <label> Sales/ month: </label>
      <select>
        <option> </option>
        <xsl:for-each select="TotalBooks/books">
          <option onclick="TryOption();">
            <xsl:value-of select="@month"/>
          </option>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table id="tabla">
        <tr bgcolor="skyblue">
          <th align="left">Tittle</th>
          <th align="left">Author</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="TotalBooks/books/book">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="tittle"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script>
          function TryOption(value)
          {
              $('.book').hide();
              if(value != '') {
                 $('.' + value).show();
              }
          }
        </script>
        <style>
          .book { display: none; }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>My books</h1>
        <div>
          <label> Sales/ month: </label>
          <select onchange="TryOption(this.value);">
            <option> </option>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TotalBooks/books" />
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          <table id="tabla">
            <tr bgcolor="skyblue">
              <th align="left">Tittle</th>
              <th align="left">Author</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TotalBooks/books/book" />
          </table>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="books">
    <option value="{@month}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@month"/>
    </option>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book">
    <tr class="book {../@month}">
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="tittle"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Main points:

- Moved the event handler to the `onchange` event of the `select`
- Addition of `value` attributes to the `option` elements
- Addition of classes to identify books by month
- Use of JavaScript to hide and show items by their classes

Answer (score 1):

To get to the working code, you'll need to do several things:

**Step 1** - Fix your XML file

Your `<title`> tag is closed with `</titleo>` which is obviously wrong.

**Step 2** - Fix your XSLT file

Add the XSLT document declaration, so it is formed as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <!-- Rest of the stylesheet may be here -->
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Step 3** - Rethink your code

There are several issues with your code:

1. You plan to create one big table with rows for all months. This can be done, but will be more difficult to handle in JS later. It's easier to just show/hide one table, than to show/hide each row separately.
2. You are using `onclick` on `<option`>. I propose using `onchange` on `<select>`.

**Step 4** - Add more data to XML file

This will let you test your code in a more obvious way. Just copy the `<books>` for January and change month name to February.

**Step 5** - Fix XSLT

Please find the following code as an example. This code is far from being complete, but it shows you direction. Plese refer to my inline comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<html>
  <head>
  <script>
  /* <select> is a parameter */
  function TryOption(select)
  {
     /* get the name of the selected month */
     var month = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

     /* show the table corresponding to this month */
     document.getElementById('table-'+month).style.display="block";

     /* you should also hide other tables - it's not done here */
  }
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>My books</h1>
    <div>
      <label> Sales/ month: </label>

      <!-- 'onchange' event here -->
      <select onchange="TryOption(this)">
        <option></option>
        <xsl:for-each select="TotalBooks/books">
          <!-- each <option> has a 'value' attribute with the name of th month
               On example:
                <option value="January">January</option> --> 
          <option>
            <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@month"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@month"/>
          </option>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- For each <books> tag (which represents one month) create new table.
           Table's id = 'table'+month, on example 'table-January'.
           Each table is hidden by default. -->
      <xsl:for-each select="TotalBooks/books">
        <table style="display: none">
          <xsl:attribute name="id">table-<xsl:value-of select="@month"/></xsl:attribute>
          <tr bgcolor="skyblue">
            <th align="left">Tittle</th>
            <th align="left">Author</th>
          </tr>
          <!-- For each book in the given month, list those. 
               This 'for-each' only loops over books from one month,
               because this loop is inside another loop -->
          <xsl:for-each select="book">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="tittle"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```